# Update status column in codigniter is not working

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Hi guys i am trying to update the status column of my table **contentdetails** To 0.I don't know what is the exact problem and where i have done mistake i couldn't able to update my status column.

Here is my controller:

```
function deleteImage() {
    // Pass the $id to the contentDelete() method
    $id = $this->input->post('image_id');
    if ($id) {
        $this->Content_model->imageDelete($id);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Image deleted.');
        redirect('Content');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Image Id not captured.');
        redirect('Content');
    }
}
```

Here is my model:

```
function imageDelete($id) {
    $this->db->set('status', 0); //value that used to update column  
    $this->db->where('id', $id); //which row want to upgrade  
    $this->db->update('contentdetails');  //table name
}
```

Here is my view:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="dataTable1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Image path</th>
                            <th class='text-center'>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        foreach ($bgimglist as $bgimgs) {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $bgimgs->id; ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo $bgimgs->details; ?></td> 
                                <td class='text-center'>
                                     <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('Content/deleteImage'); ?>">
                                             <input type="text" name="image_id" value="<?php echo $bgimgs->id; ?>">
                                            <button type="submit" onclick="return ConfirmDelete()" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs confirmation" name="login"><i class='fas fa-times'></i></button>
                                        </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Can anyone help me where i have done mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with this `$this->db->set('status', '0');`

Comment: no its not working

Comment: did u get any error? , make sure ur `status` column not have status `0`

Comment: yes it is in 1 and i am not getting any errors too

Comment: try this and let me know what it says: `function imageDelete($id) {
    $q = $this->db->get_where('contentdetails', array('id' => $id));
    if ($q->num_rows() !== 1) {
        show_error('No row by that id');
    }
    echo 'row exists';
    $this->db->set('status', 0);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    var_dump($this->db->update('contentdetails'));
    exit;
}`

Comment: nothing i can able to see it is redirecting to content page

Comment: well that probably means that you are entering the else statement in your controller as my code exits hence preventing a redirect from being reached. instead of redirecting for debugging why don't you just echo something to know in what part of the condition you are in. troubleshooting 101

Comment: where do you want me to echo the value ?

Comment: no: i.e. `if ($id) { echo 'good'; } else { echo 'bad'; }`

Comment: okay give me 2 mins let me check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177062/discussion-between-user200-and-alex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to some misunderstanding OP though `form_open()` also closed the form in code available in the discussion in the above comments. Thus, any further form calls were going to the form that was never closed.

Adding a `</form>` for the open form solved the issue.